# What happens if I add URLs to service worker cache outside of the waitUntil() flow?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Can I add items to my service worker cache outside of the `waitUntil` workflow of the "install" event and what happens if I do? Is this a bad idea?

I have a single-page app where I want to cache the main components and assets of the app immediately upon service worker install and then lazy-cache some secondary pages that the user may not get to. Without service workers I would be dynamically importing these secondary assets so the user doesn't need to download them on first-load.

What I am doing currently is this:

```
self.addEventListener("install", e => {

    e.waitUntil(
        (async () => {
            const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
            return cache.addAll(appShell);
        })()
    );

    caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => {
        return cache.addAll(secondaryPages);
    });
});
```

`secondaryPages` is being cached by the SW, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it. I'm expecting the above code to say "don't finish installing until appShell is cached, but don't wait on `secondaryPages`".

Does this give me the lazy performance boost I'm looking for or should I be adding the `secondaryPages` to the cache at a later time, say a message event fired from the app once things are loaded in the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised I could use a `setTimeout` to mimic a slow response to the secondary cache to see how the app would behave.

```
caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        cache.addAll(secondaryManifest);
        console.log("added secondary cache");
    }, 1000 * 20);
});
```

With this, the SW installs correctly, caching the main app shell. 20 seconds later, the secondary files are cached, but in meantime the app is fully useful. If the pages that need those lazy-loaded files are requested, they go through the regular fetch handling that I've set up (check cache, then go to the network if needed). This could lead to the `cache.addAll` in the `setTimeout` overwriting those items in the cache, but that shouldn't really be an issue, at least not from a UX point of view, though the SW may be double downloading.

So yes, using `cache.addAll` outside of `waitUntil` works, and will just cache the files in the background while the app and SW continue on their merry way. This allows for more efficient SW installation.